# rtspclientsink test pipeline from command line

Tags: linux, gstreamer, pipeline, rtsp-client

I would like to stream with rtsp using GStreamer pipeline elements. First, I checked with gst-inspect-1.0 that rtspclientsink is available:

```
xilinx-k26-starterkit-2020_2:/# gst-inspect-1.0 | grep rtsp
rtspclientsink:  rtspclientsink: RTSP RECORD client
rtsp:  rtspsrc: RTSP packet receiver
rtsp:  rtpdec: RTP Decoder
```

Then, wrote simplest pipeline and tested it with videotestsrc as source and kmssink as the sink. Following pipeline works well:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080 ! kmssink bus-id=fd4a0000.zynqmp-display fullscreen-overlay=1 sync=false
```

Then, changed sink to rtspclientsink:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080 !  rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:554/test
```

However, even with a simple pipeline, stream could not be started and encountered with the error:

```
xilinx-k26-starterkit-2020_2:/# gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=1920,height=1080 ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:554/test
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://localhost:554/test
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPClientSink:rtspclientsink0: Could     not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
../../../gst-rtsp-server-1.16.1/gst/rtsp-sink/gstrtspclientsink.c(3236):     gst_rtsp_client_sink_connect_to_server (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0    /GstRTSPClientSink:rtspclientsink0:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Could anyone enlighten me about the error and the way I can use rtspclientsink as a sink? I also considered to stream with a script (given below) which uses rtsp server as follows but I wonder is it possible to use rtspclientsink as an pipeline element.Thanks.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#define DEFAULT_RTSP_PORT "9001"
...(some code)
/* create a server instance */
server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();
g_object_set (server, "service", port, NULL);
mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);

factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, argv[1]);
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared (factory, TRUE);
...(some code that creates pipeline and calls rtsp stream function)
```

Comment: Found an rtspclientsink example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088647/16748533. *gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! queue ! x264enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test* tested and encountered with the same error: 'ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPClientSink:rtspclientsink0: Could not open resource for reading and writing.'

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this ? I'm at the same point. I have a feeling that besides starting the pipeline you also need to start a rtsp-server application.. but i'm not sure as i can't find any documentation on how to use it

Answer (score 4):

download rtsp-simple server from

https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server/releases

unzip and run it

```
tar xvf rtsp-simple-server_v0.19.3_linux_amd64.tar.gz
./rtsp-simple-server
```

it will tell you what port it's listening on

```
2022/07/31 13:23:34 INF rtsp-simple-server v0.19.3
2022/07/31 13:23:34 INF [RTSP] listener opened on :8554 (TCP), :8000 (UDP/RTP), :8001 (UDP/RTCP)
2022/07/31 13:23:34 INF [RTMP] listener opened on :1935
2022/07/31 13:23:34 INF [HLS] listener opened on :8888
```

point your rtsp stream at it (change localhost to the server hosting the rtsp-simple-server if you are sending over network)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
```

Check rtsp-simple-server console log

```
2022/07/31 13:26:02 INF [RTSP] [conn 192.168.1.130:34932] opened
2022/07/31 13:26:02 INF [RTSP] [session 247376253] created by 192.168.1.130:34932
2022/07/31 13:26:03 INF [RTSP] [session 247376253] is publishing to path 'mystream', 1 track with UDP
```

open vlc-player -> Media -> Open Network Stream

[image]

Press Play

vlc should show a test pattern

you will see below in rtsp-simple-server console log

```
2022/07/31 13:27:10 INF [RTSP] [conn 127.0.0.1:53900] opened
2022/07/31 13:27:10 INF [RTSP] [session 749381985] created by 127.0.0.1:53900
2022/07/31 13:27:10 INF [RTSP] [session 749381985] is reading from path 'mystream', 1 track with UDP
```