# Setting up a custom gstreamer appsrc in python for rtsp streaming

Tags: python, gstreamer

I want to set up a an appsrc to stream custom data e.g. arbitary image like numpy matrices using the gstreamer pipeline in python. For this I use an GstAppSrc in push mode.
This works fine for just displaying the data using an autovideosink but doesn't seem to work with any encoders for example writing jpeg as .avi or streaming h264 as rtsp stream.

As the full application is too complex I tried to make a small example where I create a 100x100 RGB matrix in numpy and push it with a custom GstAppSrc.

I tried to follow [this example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html?gi-language=python) (which was written in C) and parse it into python code.

The pipeline works as long as I don't have to encode my data and use an `autovideosink` to directly display it.
Using any type of encoder cause either the pipeline to block or throw errors like:

> (python:178667): GStreamer-Video-CRITICAL **: 15:50:56.078: gst_pad_set_caps: assertion 'caps != NULL && gst_caps_is_fixed (caps)' failed

Which IMHO doesn't make sense as I set and fixate caps on the buffer and my GstAppSrc.

For setting up an rtsp stream I follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186851/20580911

Here is my Demo Program for testing the pipeline:

```py
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass

import numpy as np

import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstApp', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstVideo, GstApp, GLib

Gst.init()


@dataclass
class AppSrcSharedData:
    pipeline: Gst.Pipeline
    app_src: GstApp.AppSrc
    source_id: int
    main_loop: GLib.MainLoop
    frame_ctr: int
    color_val: int


def create_color_tile(hue_val):
    red = 1
    green = 1
    blue = 1
    if hue_val <= 120:
        red = 1 - (hue_val / 120)
        green = hue_val / 120
        blue = 0
    elif hue_val <= 240:
        red = 0
        green = 1 - ((hue_val-120) / 120)
        blue = ((hue_val-120) / 120)
    elif hue_val <= 360:
        red = ((hue_val-240) / 120)
        green = 0
        blue = 1 - ((hue_val-240) / 120)
    return np.full((100, 100, 3), (255 * np.asarray([red, green, blue])), dtype=np.uint8)


def _push_data(data: AppSrcSharedData):
    buffer = Gst.Buffer.new_wrapped(create_color_tile(data.color_val).tobytes())
    buffer.add_reference_timestamp_meta(data.app_src.get_caps(), data.app_src.get_current_running_time(), Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
    buffer.pts = data.app_src.get_current_running_time()
    buffer.dts = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE
    buffer.duration = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE
    buffer.offset = data.frame_ctr
    data.frame_ctr += 1

    ret = data.app_src.push_buffer(buffer)

    data.color_val += 1
    time.sleep(0.03)
    if data.color_val > 360:
        data.app_src.end_of_stream()
        data.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        data.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        data.main_loop.quit()
        return False

    if ret != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def _start_feed(appsrc, length, udata):
    udata.source_id = GLib.idle_add(_push_data, udata)

def _stop_feed(appsrc, udata):
    GLib.source_remove(udata.appsrc_data.source_id)
    udata.appsrc_data.source_id = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipe_str = "appsrc name=source ! videoconvert ! autovideosink"
    # pipe_str = ("appsrc name=source format=time is_live=True ! videoconvert ! openh264enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test")
    # pipe_str = "appsrc name=source format=time is_live=True ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=output.avi"
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipe_str)
    src = None
    for element in pipeline.children:
        if element.name == "source":
            src = element
    # configure appsrc
    src.set_stream_type(GstApp.AppStreamType.STREAM)
    src.set_live(True)
    src.set_do_timestamp(False)
    src.set_format(Gst.Format.TIME)

    # set caps
    video_info = GstVideo.VideoInfo()
    video_info.set_format(GstVideo.VideoFormat.RGB, 100, 100)
    video_caps = video_info.to_caps()
    video_caps.fixate()
    src.set_caps(video_caps)

    main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    appsrc_data = AppSrcSharedData(pipeline, src, 0, main_loop, 0, 0)

    # connect callbacks
    src.connect("need-data", _start_feed, appsrc_data)
    src.connect("enough-data", _stop_feed, appsrc_data)
    ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    main_loop.run()
```

Can someone help me figure out if I am missing a parameter set-up or configuration for encoding to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `pipe_str` for

```py
    pipe_str = """
    appsrc name="source" ! tee name=video_tee
    video_tee. ! queue  name=display_queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
    video_tee. ! queue  name=enc_queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 byte-stream=true key-int-max=30 bframes=0 aud=true pass=cbr speed-preset=superfast threads=8 analyse=i8x8 sliced-threads=true ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=output.ts
    """
```

works out of the box with your code (Ubuntu 22.04, GStreamer 1.22.6). The pipeline branches the input from your `appsrc` into an `autovideosink` for displaying and another branch for encoding and storing in a TS file. These encoder settings may help you in setting up your RTSP client sink.

The `output.ts` can be opened using VLC, for instance, the codec stats look like this:

[image]

Some things you might want to add:

- Set the framerate of your input video so the encoder works properly:

  ```py
  # set caps
  video_info = GstVideo.VideoInfo()
  video_info.set_format(GstVideo.VideoFormat.RGB, 100, 100)
  video_info.fps_n = 30  # or whatever value from your app
  video_info.fps_d = 1   # same
  ```
- Flush the `appsrc` element when the pipeline is about to stop so any downstream element finishes its work. I noticed that without this, I got about 6 seconds of video in the `output.ts` file instead of the expected 12s.

```py
def _push_data(data: AppSrcSharedData):
    buffer = Gst.Buffer.new_wrapped(create_color_tile(data.color_val).tobytes())
    buffer.add_reference_timestamp_meta(data.app_src.get_caps(), data.app_src.get_current_running_time(), Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
    buffer.pts = data.app_src.get_current_running_time()
    buffer.dts = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE
    buffer.duration = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE
    buffer.offset = data.frame_ctr
    data.frame_ctr += 1

    ret = data.app_src.push_buffer(buffer)

    data.color_val += 1
    time.sleep(0.03)
    if data.color_val > 360:
        data.app_src.end_of_stream()
        data.app_src.send_event(Gst.Event.new_flush_start())
        data.app_src.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        data.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        data.main_loop.quit()
        return False

    if ret != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

With that, the stats of the `output.ts` video look like:

[image]